# Как сделать так чтоб при нажатии на ссилку отправлялась форма?

Tags: html, django, html-form

У меня есть вот  такая форма:

```
<form action="{% url 'cart-update' object.slug %}" id="cart_form" method="post">
...
...
...
...
<a id="add_to_cart" class="s_main_color_bgr" form="cart_form" type="submit" href=""><span class="s_text"><span class="s_icon"></span> Add to Cart</span></a>
</form>
```

Я прописал разние атрибути для тега **a** но оно не работает, как ето сделать чтоб оно работало и какие атрибути прописать?

Заранее спасибо!

P.S: если ето вообще можно сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для отправки формы надо использовать не ссылку, а кнопку. Если хочешь, чтобы выглядела как ссылка, используй css.

Answer (score -2):

Отправка формы осуществляется с помощью `<input type="submit">` внутри самой формы. Если нужно отправить данные, а потом перейти на какую-либо страницу, нужно прописать переадресацию в файл, указанный в атрибуте action.

Например
HTML

```
<form action= "index.php" method="POST">
```

index.php

```
header('Location: ../profile/profile.php')
```

Comment: ChatGPT запрещён - за его использование бан на неделю.

Comment: Я его и не использовал